# error: no matching function for call

Tags: c++, class, constructor, arguments

I'm calling a one argument constructor and I'm getting an error that seems to read that I'm calling a no argument constructor (which doesn't and shouldn't exist).

This is the error I'm getting

```
g++ -g -c predictor.C
In file included from predictor.C:5:
PHT.C: In constructor 'PHT::PHT(int)':
PHT.C:5: error: no matching function for call to'TwoBitPredictorTable::TwoBitPredictorTable()'
TwoBitPredictorTable.C:5: note: candidates are: TwoBitPredictorTable::TwoBitPredictorTable(int)
predictor.h:25: note: TwoBitPredictorTable::TwoBitPredictorTable(const TwoBitPredictorTable&)
```

Here is the constructor call on line 5 in PHT.C

```
PHT::PHT(int rows)
{
    predictor = TwoBitPredictorTable(rows);
}
```

The class definition for PHT is:

```
class PHT
{
TwoBitPredictorTable predictor;

public:
    PHT(int rows);
    bool update(unsigned int pc, unsigned int ghr, bool outcome);
    bool getPrediction(unsigned int pc, unsigned int ghr);
};
```

The idea is to make a class PHT which wraps a TwoBitPredictorTable.

I'm pretty new to C++, but after hours of searching for an answer, I'm asking for your help. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the constructor in the initialization list. What you have now is equivalent to:

```
PHT::PHT(int rows) :
    predictor() // <-- error, no default constructor
{
    predictor = TwoBitPredictorTable(rows);
}
```

Instead:

```
PHT::PHT(int rows) :
    predictor(rows)
{
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, I'm not familiar with initialization lists, but now I know where to look. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `TwoBitPredictorTable` has no default constructor. You should use the initializer list to construct `TwoBitPredictorTable` during PHT construction.

```
PHT::PHT(int rows) : predictor(rows)
{
}
```

Should look something like this.